# How to convert NSString with negative integer into negative integer

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, signed, signed-integer

In my app, I want to display `0` if NSString contains negative integers. I tried to convert NSString into signed int but my NSString to signed int conversion code always returns `0` value.

> Eg: I want to convert `@"-0.02"` into `-0.02 int`. But my code always returns `0` instead original value.

I tried with below code:

1. `(signed)[@"-0.02" intValue]` //returns 0
2. `[[NSNumberFormatter new] numberFromString:timespent]` //returns NSNumber with -0.02 value but while do `< 0` comparison, I converted `NSNumber` into `signedIntValue` as `(signed)[[[NSNumberFormatter new] numberFromString:timespent] intValue]` //but it returns 0

Anyone knows how to do that in iOS - Objective-c?

Comment: float numFloat = [@"-0.02" floatValue]; // returns -0.02.

Comment: You should try to use this `NSString* value = @"-123"; intValueOfString = [value IntergerValue];`.
Instead of **intValue** use **intergerValue**

Comment: You should read the translation of "integer" (int) in your language, or know the mathematics signification of it.

Comment: Note: int is an integer and integer is a round number like 1,2,3,4,5. You can not have a -0.02 int as you specified in your question because -0.02 is a float and not an int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `double` instead of `int`

You string value is `double` not `integer`.

```
   NSString *numberString = @"-0.02";

   double value = [numberString doubleValue];
   NSLog(@"%.2f", value);  //-0.02
```

Comment: i think  double d = [numberString doubleValue]; is better.

Comment: use double is better else another way use containsstring concept for handle